# simple jQuery UI drag and drop example

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to enable each of the list items classed "draggable" to be drag enabled for dropping into the #content div. However, the first problem is that I'm not getting an alert on the click handler. What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url('', __FILE__)?>/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.draggable').click
    (
        function()
        {
            alert('clicked'); //DOES NOT FIRE
            jQuery(this).draggable();
            jQuery( "#content" ).droppable
            ({  
                drop: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                    //drop/paste jQuery(this).text(); 
                }
            });
        });
</script>

<ul class="keywords">
    <li class="draggable" id="kw-1">keyword one</li>
    <li class="draggable" id="kw-2">keyword two</li>
    <li class="draggable" id="kw-3">keyword three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if your jquery is loaded correctly? Your script only shows that you are loading jquery-ui.js.

Otherwise, your code works when both jquery and jquery-ui are loaded.

Comment: I'm using WordPress enqueue > wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

Comment: I think I've got an object clash issue. Thanks for the help ace.

Comment: No problem, hope you found the conflict issues.